# Microsoft Access Connection using Python error

Tags: python, database, ms-access, odbc

```
import pyodbc
from PIL import Image
import io

# Connect to the Access database
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:/Users/MeriAnes/Desktop/base5.mdb;'
)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# SQL query to select the image data
query = "SELECT ImageColumn FROM TableName"

# Execute the query
cursor.execute(query)

# Iterate over the rows and process each image
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    # Assuming the image is stored as bytes in the "ImageColumn"
    image_bytes = row.ImageColumn
    # Remove the OLE header (assuming it's 78 bytes)
    image_without_header = image_bytes[78:]
    # Create an image object from the bytes
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_without_header))
    # Process the image as needed
    # For example, you can save it to a file
    image.save("processed_image.jpg")

# Close the connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft Access database (.mdb file) using python, but I have the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\users\merianes.spyder-py3\temp.py:10
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] Source de données introuvable et nom de pilote non spécifié (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Just to inform you , the list of Installed ODBC drivers in my laptop are:

SQL Server
ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)
MySQL ODBC 8.3 ANSI Driver
MySQL ODBC 8.3 Unicode Driver